# Sending a javascript variable to php cookie variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables, cookies

The code is like this, however it seems not to be working. Please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var name=prompt("Please enter your name");
</script>
<?php

$_COOKIE['user']=$_GET['name'];
?>
```

Comment: that is not the way to send var

Comment: Just set a cookie with JS, PHP will be able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing PHP (which runs on server side) with  JavaScript (which runs on client side). This is fundamentally impossible. PHP is run long before the JavaScript part.

You probably want to use JavaScript [to set the cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). PHP will be able to read it on the next request.

Comment: The code that I used above is in fact a .php file. But why is the value in name not being send to the "user" cookie variable. (NB. The cookie has been declared somewhere else.) Please help.

Comment: @prince because PHP runs on server side. The *result* of the PHP script is then sent to the client as the HTML file that you see in your browser. JavaScript gets executed only *then*. It is impossible for JavaScript to interact with PHP in this way. Use JavaScript to set the cookie as shown in the link